# I am able to aply firebase realtime database query for on variable on value i want to apply query for two values to the same variable

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am able to apply firebase realtime database query for on variable on value I want to apply query for two value to the same variable

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Spot").child(country).orderByChild(viewCate).equalTo(set_query);
```

I want to list both  data `setquery="Burger"` and data `setquery="Piza"` but not data `setquery="Noodles"`

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please also indicate the exact data you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way out here to query both `Burger` and `Piza` at the same time.

For such cases, you have to query twice, once with `burger` and second time with `Piza` and then merge both results in your code manually.